# Eggs on the Roof!

Tags: lateral-thinking

A small family of chickens were discussing very important business, the conversation went like this:

"The farmer needs eggs! Someone has to lay them!"

"No quiet down! You have to be quiet! The farmer will hear you!"

"But mom!"

"No buts! I'll lay the eggs! Go back to your rooms!"

"Fine!"

Later that night 2 chicks woke up. Chick#1 told Chick#2 "I can lay eggs!" Chick#2 said "Prove it!"

So he went to the roof, and laid as many eggs as he could!

Which way did the eggs roll? Towards the left or right?

**The roof is shaped like a triangular prism.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The eggs didn't roll either way since there were no eggs since the chick (he) was male and therefore couldn't lay eggs. So, looks like Chick #1 lost the dare.

Comment: Also, chicks are baby chickens, right?